# Gradle downloading dependency into cache instead of maven repository

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependency-management

I am trying to maintain the same repository on my filesystem for maven and gradle. But I am running into some problems.

I have the following in my `build.gradle` file.

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '2.3.9'
    runtime group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '2.3.9'
    runtime 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.8.7'
}
```

GRADLE_HOME is `D:\Programming\Java\gradle-2.2.1`
GRADLE_USER_HOME is `D:\Programming\Java\.m2`

My gradle home is the same as my Maven repository.

But when the dependencies are downloaded via gradle they are being downloaded into the `GRADLE_USER_HOME\cache` instead of the repository folder. What configuration am I missing?

**EDIT**
I have checked the chapter on dependency management of the book `Gradle In Action`. Nothing. I have checked the [dependency management](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) on gradle's website but it also just says that cache is used.

It seems that there is no such option available in gradle. Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no setting to change that. There is no gradle repository as such. Also, it seems like a bad idea to have gradle use the repository's folder as dependency cache because of the clutter.

If you are trying to publish artifacts built by gradle to said maven repository, you should probably take a look at the [maven-publish](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) plugin.

If you are trying to use artifacts from that repository in your build, the way to go would be to add `mavenLocal()` to your repositories and then just use the `compile` function in your dependencies.

Comment: I know about both of the above things. The part is what if I want the artifact to be placed in maven repository so I can reuse in other gradle/maven builds? The way I am currently doing it by firstly downloading it via Maven and then using it in Maven/gradle as needed.

Comment: @AseemBansal You want to put it there so you don't have to redownload it when you perform other builds that use the same (external) artifact? If gradle already has an artifact in its cache, it'll reuse wherever it can.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I want. But Maven will not use that artifact. I need maven because the support for [gradle is broken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22339142/gradle-1-10-internal-maven-repository-indexing-forever-in-intellij-13) in IntellijIdea I cannot start using gradle everywhere. Also for some odd reason gradle is downloading dependencies and not reusing dependencies from cache if they are not present in the local repository.

Comment: You could write a custom gradle task to copy the cache over to the maven repo. As for IDEAs gradle integration being broken, all I can say is I don't use it. I prefer the cli.

Comment: Also gradle isn't built to mess with maven's files at all. Using multiple buildsystems in parallel is always a hassle.

Comment: I though in change the Maven Local Repository to the Gradle's `caches` directory. But Gradle stores the new dependencies in other way.

Comment: Although still in `2019` there is no such direct `gradle` option, but just wanted to mention, there are [tools](https://github.com/top-master/GradleCopy) and [plugins](https://github.com/ysb33r/ivypot-gradle-plugin) that may do something like what the OP asks, but in another way ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I read the source code and just confirmed **There is no setting to change that.**

Here is my solution:

1. install a local maven repository manager like Nexus.
2. config gradle using that repository.