# Can maven and gradle share the same folder as local repository?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I have maven and gradle installed on my machine. For maven projects, maven downloads dependencies into .m3 folder or, if specified, another location.
Gradle downloads dependencies into gradle folder. The same as for maven, I can use another location. Directory structure of maven and gradle repositories are different.

Can I use one location for both? If I have downloaded dependencies for maven project, do I need to download them for gradle project as well? Let's assume, I have the same code with the same dependencies, but one uses maven as a build tool, and another - gradle.

Comment: question already discussed here :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27752463/gradle-downloading-dependency-into-cache-instead-of-maven-repository .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle downloading dependency into cache instead of maven repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27752463/gradle-downloading-dependency-into-cache-instead-of-maven-repository)

Answer (score 1):

For gradle you can use

```
mavenLocal()
```

If location of repository must be in other place you can use

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url '/path/to/your/repository'
    }
}
```

Comment: It is the project configuration. And for this project gradle will check dependencies in the maven repository **without downloading them** into gradle local repository folder, right?

Comment: It can be added to project configuration or global configuration add it to GRADLE_HOME/init.gradle. Yes it not downloads dependencies to gradle local repository.